# i can't load a img from my instance image

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

hi im trying load a image from my media folder and is not working, i have as output that my `{{ image.image.url }}` display `/media/products/yo.jpg` here is my structure[image]

this is my block where i want to load the images that are in the instance of images.
also i think my code is not good maybe you can give some advice.

```
{% block content %}

<!-- all products-->
<section >

        {% for product in products %}
            {% for image in images %}
        <div class="product">
        <img src="{% static 'img/vaca.jpg' %}" class="imgpro">
        <div class="info">
        <p>
            <h3> Product: </h3> {% if image.product.pk == product.pk %} <img src='{{ image.image.url }}' class="imgpro"> {% endif %}
            <h3> Offer: </h3> <a href="{% url 'ganagroapp:product_detail' pk=product.pk %}">{{ product.product }}</a>
            <h3> Description: </h3> {{ product.description }}

        </p>
        </div>

        </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

    </section>
    {% endblock content %}
```

this is my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

app_name = 'ganagroapp'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_category, name='product_category'),
    url(r'^product/new/$', views.new_product, name='new_product'),
    url(r'^login/$',login,{'template_name':'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',logout,{'template_name':'index.html'},name='logout'),
]

this  is my view

    def index(request):
        images = Image.objects.select_related()
        category = Category.objects.select_related()
        products = Product.objects.select_related()
        return render(request,'ganagroapp/index.html', {'category' : category, 'products' : products, 'images': images} )
```

this is the settings file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'ganagroapp', 'media')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('ganagroapp:index')
```

Comment: add your settings.py MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in this post

Comment: already edited with the settings file

Comment: Did you add this : urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in your urls.py

Comment: not i dont have that, i did add but output this error:  'urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is occured because you did not add the last line in your urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```